# Css question...newbie/beginner

Tags: html, css

I am beginning to make my first website and I so far have a menu and all but the problem is I don't know how to use an external css for formatting....

What I mean by that is, I DO KNOW in an external css if I put `body { background-color: yellow}` and use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />` it will apply yellow to background color of my website.

What I can't figure out is how can I use a css file to apply the menu and fonts to all of the web pages I make....I don't want to post this same css code in every web page as the tutorial I am following says it is good programming to just import a css file into all the web pages you want to apply the format to instead of pasting that css code into each and every one....

Here is my code, basically what I want to know is how can I put the css part of the code into a css file so I can call it for all my web pages instead of putting it into my code directly, beware the css changes according to what browser you are using for blur etc.

In short: **What will my CSS file look like and what will my htm file look like for code?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Blurry Menu</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #1a1a1a url(bg.jpg);
        }

        #blur {
                position: relative;
                top: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                border: 2px solid #000000;
                border-style: solid none;
        }

        #blur:before {
                     position: absolute;
                     top: 0px;
                     width: 100%;
                   height: 100%;
                   border-top: 2px solid #212121;
                     content: '';
                 }

                #blur:after {

                    position: absolute;

                    width: 100%;

                    height: 100%;

                    top: 1px;

                    border-bottom: 2px solid #212121;

                    content: '';

                }

                #blur ul {

                    position: relative;

                    top: 0;

                    width: 960px;

                    margin: 0 auto;
                   list-style-type: none;

                 overflow: hidden;

                }

                    #blur li {

                        float: left;

                        position: relative;

                    }

                      #blur a {

                            position: relative;

                            float: left;

                            padding: 20px 25px;

                            margin-left: 10px;

                            text-decoration: none;

                            font-family: "trebuchet ms";

                            font-variant: small-caps;

                           color: transparent;

                            text-shadow: 0 0 2px #cacaca;

                            z-index: 100;

                        }

                /* normal styles */
                    #blur a:hover, #blur a:focus {

                       color: #ffffca;

                      text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;

                   }

                /* active styles */

                    #blur .active a, #blur .active a:hover {

                        color: #cacaca;

                        text-shadow: 0 0 2px #cacaca;

                    }

    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>

        <style type="text/css">

           #blur {

               -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#212121,direction=180,strength=0)";

                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#212121,direction=180,strength=0);

            }

            #blur ul li a {

                color: #ffffca;

                -ms-filter:  "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur()";

                filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur();

            }

            #blur ul a:hover, #blur ul .active a, #blur ul a:focus {

                position: relative;

               margin: 2px 0 -10px 10px;

                -ms-filter:  "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(enabled = false)";

                filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(enabled = false);

            }

        </style>

    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <style type="text/css">

           #blur ul a:hover, #blur ul .active a {

                position: relative;

                margin: 2px 4px 0 10px;

                filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(enabled = false);

           }

        </style>

   <![endif]-->

</head>



<body>

    <div id="blur">

        <ul>

            <li>

                <a href="http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/website.php">Home</a>

            </li>

            <li>

                <a href="http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/How-to.htm">How-to</a>

            </li>

            <li class="active">

                <a href="http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/Edit.php">Edit</a>

            </li>

            <li>

                <a href="#">Features</a>

            </li>

            <li>

                <a href="#">Services</a>

            </li>

            <li>

                <a href="#">Contact</a>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/how-to-add-external-css-in-a-html-file

Comment: Again, you just make the one .css file, separate from all your html pages. Then you use the <link> tag that 10 people have recommended in the <head> of each page. Thus, you write one style sheet (.css file) and use it as a reference for all your pages. Your css  `body {            background: #1a1a1a url(bg.jpg);    etc, etc    }`... is all that goes in your css file, nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your CSS to a new file, say, "style.css" and import the stylesheet in your webpages. To do this, add the following tag to the HEAD section of your HTML:

```
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
```

For more details, I recommend you go through [this page](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html).

Comment: i already tried what you guys said a long time ago.....there is some problem with it where it wont import my background image and the borders are messed up...

Comment: May be your href path is not correct. Did you confirm your image paths are proper? Also, you need to use exact class/id selectors in your css as in your HTML mark up. I suggest you use firebug (a firefox extension) for debugging the problem.

Comment: PS: close this thread thanks to everyone dev_musings you were kind of right I had 5 css sheets in there and I had the name wrong of the one I wanted to use so it was trying to fetch a background picture not even there...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Place your style sheet within your header, e.g.

```
<head>
    <title>My Awesome Site</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

...with the `href` referencing the location of your style sheet.  Then you may apply the style sheet rules the same as if you had an internal stylesheet.

When you create your external style sheet, just remember, don't include `<style>` tags inside of the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tizag.com/cssT/external.php. Will tell you how.

Comment: That site's down. What did it say?

Comment: The same as george's answer. He posted at the same time as me. Put your css in a file named something.css (or in george's answer StyleSheet.css) and in your head use the <link> tag to add the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" />
```

Is what you want. I suggest reading over http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp for basics.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css" type="text/css" media=">`

This needs to be placed in the `head` section of you page.

The `href` references the path to the file.

You can also use the `@import` method.

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("/css/master.css");
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your inline styles in a document and name it with the extension .css. Then reference it between your  tags with the following line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css" type="text/css" />
```

The href can be both relative (../images/file.css) or absolute (/images/file.css).

If you need to access different media, you can put in a media tag (like media="screen") or media="print" for stylesheet only to be used when printing a page.

Answer (score 0):

As the html5 evolved you can declare ur document type <!doctype> and utilise the external css 
by placing all the css in a file named style.css and then u can acess it with

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css"/>

and embed ur css into your website

> NOTE:In html5 type is optional