# How to link an external stylesheet in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been using html with internal style sheets for a while now until my friend told me about external css style sheets. How can I link an external style sheets to CSS? Also what are the benifets of external style sheeting?

Comment: this question is not worth answering :|

Comment: By internal stylesheets do you mean using the `<style>` tags in the head of the document?

Comment: Ask your friend about Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding external CSS in an HTML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file)

Comment: Google "css tutorial".

Comment: He realy needs someone (Google) to talk about his 'serious' problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link your external style sheet put this code in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

The Benifets of using an External Style Sheets is that you can change the look/style of your website with only editing one file. With internal style sheets you need to type the code for every page.

Answer (score 1):

Other's have answered the how-to part. As for benefits:

- (as Jabel states) you can reuse the same CSS on every page (which you typically need to do for a web site)
- (as jaydx49 states) you have one central place to edit all the CSS (much easier to update one file than 50, for example)
- If all your CSS is in one file, and it's used on every page, that means the browser only has to download the CSS information once, and can then cache it for every other page. This makes your web site download faster.
- It's easier to compress (minify) your CSS if it's all in separate files, again making the site download faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your **`<head>`** in your HTML the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE">
```

The benefits are that you have more clear an clean code. And you can use it in all your HTML files that you want, and if you change your CSS code you will affect all the files that are using it.