# My <p> text wont show; any idea why?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use this code to make a scrollable website but my `<p>` text won't show. Does anyone have any idea why? I have tried adding both the class as the item reference, but this is not really helping. the link is http://remcovanessen.users41.interdns.co.uk/beerbulance/ if that helps

```
<body data-hijacking="off" data-animation="scaleDown">
    <section class="cd-section visible">
        <div>
            <h2 class="homepageheader">Beerbulance</h2>
            <p> text</p>
        </div>
    </section>

cd-section {
  height: 100vh;
}
.cd-section h2 {
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.cd-section h2.homepageheader{
  font-size: 800%;
}
.cd-section:first-of-type > div {
  background-color: #09c003;
}
.cd-section:first-of-type > div::before {
  /* alert -> all scrolling effects are not visible on small devices */
  content: 'Effects not visible on mobile!';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #09c003;
```

Comment: Why is the styling in the page like this, you need to wrap it in a `style` tag or on another page and import it into your page

Comment: Better yet: put it in a `.css` file and link to it using a `link` tag. [You can do it this way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1947878/3471286)

Comment: Thanks... I couldnt upload all of it because the site didnt allow me but its actually part of the .css file.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set `line-height: 100vh` on `.cd-section h2` element. It is currently taking the space of your viewport and pushing the `p` element below it. If you can't remove/change the line-height set your `p` element margin to :

```
p {
  margin-top: -16px
}
```

This will show you the text at the bottom left.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but it also makes the background smaller... but I think i can fix that. cheers :)

Comment: @Webbro Cool! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

It gets pushed out of the way from your h2 headline `<h2 class="homepageheader">Beerbulance</h2>`.
You need to re-think your HTML structure.