# How to include PHP header and link css files to it?

Tags: php

I came to know that we could actually dd our header/footer/navigation bar using PHP.I added it and it worked great but i don't know how to add it's related stylesheet. Should i just link in to the header and footer files in their HTML files?Like header.php and link header.css to it?

Comment: Do you mean the stylesheet doesn't work when you use `include('filename.php');`?

Comment: Try to follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1947898/2253302

Answer (score 0):

Include header file anywhere you want.

```
<?php
   include 'header.php';
?>
```

And inside header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
```

href="full path of header.css"

Comment: Thank you very much!i have got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add a stylesheet link to your php page in header tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
```