# Is it posible to use CSS in this way in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to use CSS within PHP code but it seems that I can't use CSS in the way that I'm trying. why?

```
<?php   
   $username = "Daved";
   $password = "hello!";
?>

<html>
   <head>
   </head>

   <body>

   <?php

      echo "<div style="font-size: 32px; background-color:#f00; color:#fff; width:200px;">And Operation</div>";

      if($username == "Daved" && $password == "hello!"){
         echo "<p>The Password and UserName are correct!</p>";
      }
      else {
              echo "<p>You are not a member!</p>";
           }        
   ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Ok, It's a true way to use CSS like this, or I must to try using style in another way?

Comment: use css style seperatly. best+efficient +good practice+ stander-ed approach

Comment: This wont work correctly. Chnage it to `echo "<div style='font-size: 32px; background-color:#f00; color:#fff; width:200px;'>And Operation</div>";`

Comment: It a generally considered best practice to [Add external CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual Problem is your echo statement. It should be noted that the echo prints whatever is in between `" "` or `''`. Hence your statement `echo "<div style="font-size: 32px; background-color:#f00; color:#fff; width:200px;">And Operation</div>";` is closing at `style="`. Hence your code is not working change it to `echo "<div style='font-size: 32px; background-color:#f00; color:#fff; width:200px;'>And Operation</div>";`. It will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but you made a mistake

```
echo "style=" font-size:32;
```

Php will search for the method font-size:32.
It wilp not find it and this causes an error.
Use "" to define the string and use ' ' for inline css:

```
echo"style='font-size:32px'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps. I just modified your code little bit in the 1st **echo**. It just the issue of using quote operator. Thanks

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

    echo '<div style="font-size: 32px; background-color:#f00; color:#fff; width:200px;">And Operation</div>';
    if($username == "Daved" && $password == "hello!"){

        echo "<p>The Password and UserName are correct!</p>";
    }

    else {
        echo "<p>You are not a member!</p>";
    }

    ?>
    </body>

    </html>
```