# does notepad++ have a way to connect a way to use an external style.css file.?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding and have only learned how to use HTML and CSS. If I use notepad++ how do I make an external stylesheet?

Comment: Are you attempting to use the CSS file to change the Notepad++ editor or to change a website you are implementing?

Comment: i think im trying to change a website and not notepad++ itself. this is the first time i have written a code from scratch on my own.im trying to change things like font and color.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding external CSS in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file)

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser (CTRL+K or CTRL+I) and navigate to **Network** and ensure that the HTTP response code is 200 for the style sheet you include via the `link` element. If it isn't working you'll be able to boost your debugging skills by learning how to combine Apache access logs (and eventually MariaDB general query logs) with a log viewer. I highly recommend Hoo WinTail with highlight filters that allow to launch an external program (e.g. sounder.exe) that can alert you that your error matched and you know when to look at your logs: very powerful. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can add CSS styles to an HTML document by using the `<link>` element. It's documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).

Here is a simple example that assumes both files are in the same directory:

**styles.css**

```
.my-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="my-class">The background of this paragraph will be red.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```