# Changing cursor for project

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I would like to learn how to make a simple HTML file where my cursor is changed to a custom image while also being tracked with no latency across the page (same function as on my OS which is mac, but I wish to use a new cursor for a GUI project).

I have read all CSS property rules[¹](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp). The problem is these work only for when I hover over a div attribute or a button, when I want it to work permanently.

Comment: `your-element-selector { cursor:url("path/to/your/custom/cursor.png") }`

Comment: Could you be more specific, I do not understand what you mean in this statement.

Comment: The answer below explains it better.

Comment: Most of the answers here use `body` though this only takes effect when there are elements within the body for the cursor to be active on - it doesn't cover the whole page entirely whereas if you apply the rule to the `html` element itself, you can apply the cursor to the **entire** page no matter where the cursor is within the page, see my answer for more information.

Comment: @Skully Yes, I am slightly confused by these answers since the html tag is <body></body> not body {}. Could you explain which would be the preferred method to implement this?

Comment: The answers given are written in the CSS language, not HTML. To write in CSS you can either create a `.css` file to write all your properties into and [import that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file) into your HTML file, or you can add the rule directly at the top of your page within your header using the `<style>` code, I have updated my answer with an example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a custom image, you can use the `cursor: url` property within a class and specify a path to your image that you want to replace the cursor with.

```css
.cursor {
    cursor: url("image-path.png");
}
```

If you'd like to apply the cursor across the whole page, you can add the CSS rule to the `html` element.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
      html {
          cursor: url("https://i.imgur.com/8Jhi9oS.png"), auto;
      }
  </style>

  <body>
      This page has a custom cursor!
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well for me. How do I add an image I have on my computer; I have added the path "/Users/user/Downloads/47a.jpg" in the place of your "https::.." to no effect.

Comment: The path is relative to the directory that your HTML file is in, so you don't need to write the **full path** to it, for example if you have both your HTML file and image within the same folder, the file URL is just the filename and extension `url("47a.jpg")`. See [HTML File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) for more information.

Comment: Okay! There must be limitations to using a path, it only works with .cur files for me.

Comment: Are you sure the file path and extension within your `url()` are correct according to the location of your HTML file? It should work regardless of the file extension being a `.cur` file or not.

Comment: Yes, and I am running macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you mean that you want the cursor to be custom everywhere on that page you can use this:

```
body {
  cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), auto;   
}
```

If you want it only on specific parts of the website you can change the body to a class, tag or id.

Checkout https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/ for more info

Comment: What is the `, auto` part doing?

Comment: If height: auto; the element will automatically adjust its height to allow its content to be displayed correctly. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)

Comment: Sure, that's if assigned to `height`, but what is it doing in `cursor `?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of another conversation. The auto part is the fallback for if the url part does not work. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the cursor effect across the entire screen, but you can have it in the `body`:

```css
body {
  cursor: url('mycustomcursor.cur');
}
```

If you have an image that you want to use, you'll have to run it through a convertor like [Cursor Editor](https://www.cursor.cc/) and use the `.cur` file for the URL.

Comment: This is incorrect information, you can in fact have the cursor changed for the whole page by applying the rule to the `html` element directly. See my answer for an example of this.

Comment: @Skully The information is correct. There is no way you can affect the cursor outside the viewport with CSS.

Comment: OP is specifically asking for a custom cursor within the page, not the **entire window** if that is what your answer is referring to, maybe adjust your reference from 'entire screen' to 'window' to avoid confusion?

Comment: @Skully I meant ***the entire screen***, including the desktop, toolbar, and parts of the webpage's window that the webpage cannot access, such as the search bar. The fact that I said "in the body" should have clarified that.