# Why is external CSS not loaded into HTML File?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Here is the code:

```css
  body {
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>CSS Practice</title>
    <link href="Sheet.css" rel="Sheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            That is a Test For You
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I load the HTML I do not see the change that CSS should make, I could not find a solution for that.

Comment: `rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: Check if the `.css` is in the same directory as the `.html` file. If that isn't the case, try changing `href="./Sheet.css"`

Comment: Then the reason could be something else. But sheet is definitely not a valid value for rel. Any 404 errors on console?

Comment: And try hard refresh

Comment: I checked it, the problem was in rel part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding external CSS in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file)

Comment: @Ivar Unfortunately no, I already got the answer

Comment: @MarkSmith The answer you accepted tells you that you should be using `rel="stylesheet"`, which is exactly what the linked question is using. If you would have tried that, it _would_ have worked for you and so it _does_ answer your question. Having already an answer doesn't matter here. We mark questions as duplicate so that all the relevant content stays in one place. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
<link href="Sheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

A CSS document is defined with rel=”stylesheet”. Oh, and you might need to clear your cache as well.

[Learn More](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
```

[image: Result]