# Why can't I link an external style sheet to a html file?

Tags: html, css

[Here's the following code and file alignment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnKs4.png) Internal style sheets work well but I can't seem to link the same content in the external style sheet to this html file.

Comment: Please include the code directly in your question instead of showing as image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding external CSS in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the HTML files are in a folder themselves, that is where they start to look for externally linked files. If you fix the location of your CSS to `../css/mystyle.css`, that should work.

In a path, the use of `../` at the start of your path tells the browser to look in the parent directory, which in this case brings it out of the HTML folder, and then back into the CSS folder.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. This works but since my account is new I can't upvote =='.

Comment: @BàngQuỳnhAnh You should still be able to choose it as the accepted answer (tick mark under the voting arrows) to your question, but I appreciate it regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have incorrect path to your stylesheet.
Try `href="../css/mystyle.css"`