# How to load a static css file with plain Jinja, not flask, not Django?

Tags: python, css, jinja2

I can not for the life of me get tailwind working in PLAIN jinja. I just need to load the static css into the template but I do not have flask or Django so no load keyword. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding external CSS in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947878/adding-external-css-in-an-html-file)